# I get BC30205: End of statement expected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, c#-to-vb.net

I would like to know what is wrong with this VB.NET Code on Razor.

```
@grid.GetHtml("table",
               columns:=New WebGridColumn() {grid.Column("RazonSocial", "Razón Social", canSort:=True),
                                              grid.Column("FechaInicioOp", "Fecha Inicio", Function(c) c.FechaInicioOp.ToShortDateString, canSort:=True),
                                              grid.Column("Direccion.Descripcion", "Dirección", canSort:=False),
                                              grid.Column("Direccion.Estado.Nombre", "Estado", canSort:=False),
                                              grid.Column("", "",
                                                          @@<p>
                                                              @Html.ActionLink("Configurar", "Edit", New With {.IdCondominio = item("IdCondominio")}, New With {.class = "ico edit"})
                                                          </p>
                                                          )})
```

When I debug the app I get this: "BC30205: End of statement expected."

I was just trying to convert this C# code into VB.NET

```
@grid.GetHtml(
fillEmptyRows: true,
alternatingRowStyle: "fila-alternativa",
headerStyle: "encabezado-grid",
footerStyle: "pie-grid",
mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
firstText: "<< Primera",
previousText: "< Anterior",
nextText: "Siguiente >",
lastText: "Última >>",
columns: new[] {
    grid.Column("Nombre", canSort: false),
    grid.Column("Apellidos"),
    grid.Column("EMail", 
                 format: @<a href="mailto:@item.Email">@item.Email</a>
    ),
    grid.Column("FechaNacimiento", 
                header: "Fecha de nacimiento",
                format: p=>p.FechaNacimiento.ToShortDateString()
    ),
    grid.Column("NumeroDeHijos", 
                header: "Número de hijos",
                style: "a-la-derecha"
    ),
    grid.Column("",
                header: "Acciones",
                format: @<text>
```

`@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.IdPersona }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id = item.IdPersona })
</text>)

})`

But I don't know what's wrong or if is there something missing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you got the translation quite right for the columns collection.

If I change the following:

```
columns:=New WebGridColumn()
```

to read:

```
columns:=grid.Columns(
```

and then also add one more close-parentheses ')' at the end of the statement, then it works for me.

The entire statement with changes is as follows:

```
@grid.GetHtml("table",
               columns:=grid.Columns(
               {
                   grid.Column("RazonSocial", "Razón Social", canSort:=True),
                   grid.Column("FechaInicioOp", "Fecha Inicio", Function(c) c.FechaInicioOp.ToShortDateString, canSort:=True),
                   grid.Column("Direccion.Descripcion", "Dirección", canSort:=False),
                   grid.Column("Direccion.Estado.Nombre", "Estado", canSort:=False),
                   grid.Column("", "",
                   @@<p>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Configurar", "Edit", New With {.IdCondominio = item("IdCondominio")}, New With {.class = "ico edit"})
                   </p>
                   )}))
```

Hope that helps.